# Running a linux docker container and VsTest on same agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can I run a linux docker container and VsTest on same agent on a Azure Pipeline?

Windows agents do not accept run a linux container.
The linux agent do not run the VsTest task.

The main goal is to run a docker container and execute tests on it. So both must run on the same time.

Answer (score 1):

you cant do that, you need to split your build into 2 phases, one would run on a windows agent, other on linux agent

```
- job: poo1
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-16.04
  steps:
    ...

- job: pool2
  dependsOn: pool1
  pool:
    vmImage: vs2017-win2016
  steps:
    ...
```

you can do the same with visual editor

Comment: The main goal is to run a docker container and execute tests on it. So both must run on the same time. Can I achieve this with your solution?

Comment: no, you would need to host your own agent and install\configure docker on it to run linux containers on windows node, than you can achieve that